# Reason for review ban?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, review-suspension

I imagine a review ban is supposed to be a learning experience.  But when a user is presented with 7 options and a "freeform" answer, and I choose one answer (along with several other colleagues), and a ban results just saying "Please pay more attention to each review in future," what is to be learned from this interaction?

Review in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14782410.

I've tried to survey other "manual bans," but haven't learned what may have been cause for ban.  Closest thing I can find is excerpts of http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/admin-area/ were pulled to create the description.  Should reviewers be doing sentence-by-sentence checking of material to combat plagiarism? What if the author of the article in question contributed the material?

Comment: I am not super savy in tag edits... But don't we frown on c&p in them?

Comment: Downvotes?  I clearly researched, cited possible reasons for ban, and asked for clarity in two aspects, which were directly answerable and answered. If anything else, this (and similar former and future) question serves to remind manual banners to provide input as to reason for ban.

Comment: Downvoting on meta is different... Don't fret it

Answer (score 16):

That content was plagiarized from elsewhere.  A simple google search shows that this is just a copy-paste of content from elsewhere.  Yes, you as a reviewer *are* responsible for looking out for obvious cases of plagiarism, like this, and rejecting it.

Additionally, it's not actually a good tag summary.  Tag summaries are there to describe *how the tag should be used* not as a summary of the product/tool/language/concept of the tag.

Comment: Specifically, this tag wiki edit was copied from here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/admin-area/ . This tag wiki edit was flagged, and all reviewers who approved it have been banned. The ban message was the default one, so it didn't have that context.

Comment: If plagiarism is a goal to stamp out, perhaps it should be added as a reject reason.  Additionally, it has been my experience that tags describe the language, not question.  Not cherry picking, but just choosing from my question queue: `C#`, `openrasta`, `asp.net-mvc4`, `asp.net-web-api`, `azure-web-sites` all follow the "describe/summary" format, and only `C#-4.0` and `reference` follow the format you describe.

Comment: @JaimeTorres There *is* a rejection reason for plagiarism.  `This edit copies a significant amount of content from an external source. Generic descriptions such as encyclopedia articles and ad copy do not provide useful guidance; try creating something useful to this community specifically, and be sure to attribute the original author. See: How to reference material written by others.`  And yes, there are lots of tags that don't do a good job of describing their uses; it's a common problem with tag summaries in general.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I applaud the level of detail expected from review queues that I was unaware of until now.

Comment: ... and this answer would apply even if the editor was the author of the content copied from elsewhere. It's not just plagiarism that is the issue, it is that tag wiki content should be "useful to this community specifically".