# Banned for failing to recognize/check for plagiarism, 1st time... Draconian?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Today I came to review and I was informed I've been kicked off for the review queues for awhile for this:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14843211

However, to lose full review queue privileges for this seems particularly unfair to me as a first time offense, and a much grayer area.

Note that 3 other reviewers *also* approved it, so there is clearly some confusion and need to educate users better and more reasonably in that area. There have been no audits to teach/indicate show that this kind of thing is an issue. I have seen many other tag updates like this, so thought it was the norm.

Does this suggest that reviewing tag updates requires us to google the text and try to figure out the source and wording of every tag wiki update? Should we hire a lawyer or a law firm or research agency to check IP too? I'm just saying it can be hard to know where to draw the line on that stuff when it comes down to it.

To me, this is a whole new gotcha to me and I was completely caught of guard unprepared, and I think, in this case, nailing me to the wall for it is really hitting below the belt or shooting me in the back because there was really no fair warning.

It makes me want to just skip all tag wiki edits in the future so I don't guess wrong or have to spend 5 or 10 minutes or more trying to check source or authenticity on the off-chance that I'll get my derrier in the wringer if someone happens to find out it was taken wholesale from elsewhere.

I mean, even in the real world there is something call "fair use" where you're allowed to copy excerpts from proprietary documents/media. I just didn't realize plagiarism was something that happens here, or that we all as individual have to police it. It seems maybe wiki tag edits should have its own queue due to its different nature from most of the edits, which can be reviewed with more forthrightly.

I don't think you can really say (or treat me) like what I did was egregious neglect as though I was educated, trained, forewarned, and should have known better. I mean, now I know, it is an issue, but just don't think that ways the way to bring it to my attention, since I've put a lot of effort into serving and trying to do the right thing here, and I find this very discouraging.

Can I be let off with a warning this time?

Comment: That doesn't make it right.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341306/reason-for-review-ban

Comment: I hardly think it "nails you to the wall". Next time, you'll be much less likely to forget!

Comment: Why not just put banana peels on the sidewalk to teach people to watch where they're going too?

Comment: @BhargavRao yes, that is very illuminating *in retrospect*.

Comment: @clearlight People didn't intentionally suggest a plagiaristic edit just to catch you for not doing it, rather you were punished for not doing your job.  A much better analogy would be suspending the janitor for just ignoring the banana peel on the sidewalk that they're being tasked with cleaning because they didn't think it was their job to clean it up.

Comment: I didn't suggest it was a speed trap. But some here seem to almost  sociopathic in their unwillingness to give people who are contributing and trying to do the right thing the benefit of the doubt.  If I was aware that was an issue I would have guarded against it.  If you *REALLY* want to be a hardcore purist about it you'll notice that detecting plagiarism can get pretty complicated. Is the real point to bust people's chops all the time and be militant or to encourage the best behavior in the fairest way or even a kind reasonable way?

Comment: You've certainly used a lot of hyperbolic metaphors here, all in service of... getting to do more chores? Take a break. Maybe answer some questions. Find a hobby. Maybe study something that might help you gain some perspective on exactly what you're fighting for here.

Comment: Sociopathic? can we calm down on the hyperbole so the conversation can move?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The metaphors are apt. Just disregard the hyperbolic exponent and you'll notice that the points are very logical, valid and reasonable. If people want to keep beating me up in a troll pack and refusing to acknowledge ANY of the points I made, at least some of which are valid, then a little sarcasm and hyperbole in response is totally warranted in self-defense. And your 'get a hobby' bs is just snarky petty slander. I have plenty of hobbies.

Comment: @patrice I just get tired of no one giving people the benefit of the doubt or find the reasonable components of dialog but just dogpile everyone here to who try to discuss something right out of the gate. I'm tired of being guilty until proven innocent when we know some of the people here are just basically cruel trolls at heart.

Comment: @clearlight you can get tired of it, sure. Does it mean the conversation will progress if you keep up that attitude? Unfortunately, no. I get where you may be coming from, but my point is that you are hurting your argument by throwing "sociopathic", "cruel trolls" and "draconian".  If you aren't calm and can't express what you feel without using these words, you will be flogged as "just another ranter"...  (and I am SORRY... but you are guilty of approving an inappropriate edit. We can argue the punishment is harsh, but not whether or not you are guilty...)

Comment: They see me trollin. They hatin. Patrolling, they tryin to catch me ridin dirty. Well, you always have the right to remain silent.

Comment: @patrice you could save some of your wisdom in my defense as well.  I was taken aback by what happened and miffed, yes, but I was pretty reasonable until every response was intended to make me wrong and not own that there are two sides to this issue. I get impatient with that. I'm only human. Don't think anyone is above getting on the wrong side of something like this.

Comment: @patrice are you saying you don't get outraged by injustice ever?

Comment: @clearlight I am saying that I am able to remain calm and SPEAK about injustice instead of scream atop my lungs. Being able to remain calm is ALWAYS better than screaming or hyperbole. Your question saying "draconian" was there BEFORE you got any answer, so you can't say you only are reactionary.

Comment: @patrice People  have to come to meta and beg for mercy justice while the regulars and powerful sneer and pelt. Just ludicrous for so-called technocrats who are theoretically supposed to gauge arguments on their technical merits.

Comment: Slander? Nah, since I didn't say it out loud. Libel, maybe. And I still think you're blowing this way out of proportion, which, as @Patrice has noted, is not helping you. Bombast and bluster rarely help, unless you're running for political office.

Comment: @clearlight so, considering I am NOT insulting, condescending, or out to prove you wrong... why do you continue with that kind of language with me here? In any case, I am here trying to HELP you get your message across better... and I get that answer. Do you REALLY think that is warranted?

Comment: "nailing me to the wall for it is really hitting below the belt or shooting me in the back" - I'm just trying to picture that

Comment: @MichaelMyers for the sake of imagery, I guess... a nailgun through the back that nails him on the wall?

Comment: @Patrice But that's above the belt.

Comment: @Servy I don't see an XOR there, so I stand by my answer :D

Comment: Whenever I get caught in private doing something dumb, I usually pretend it didn't happen, rather than run around shouting about it.

Comment: To be completely honest, I downvoted this without reading it first because Draconian.

Comment: Hey, sorry I'm right, ...

Comment: see also: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: Yeah but from the possible duplicate: "The plagiarized part must be substantial such that it qualifies as creative content. This should be determined by a moderator, but it's generally clear cut."  That was a very short passage of something that could hardly be characterize as creative. Just saying...

Comment: And... "How long should the ban be? I don't think this needs to be long at all - just long enough to get the reviewers' attention. A single day would suffice in the vast majority of cases." - First offense, and I didn't even know it was an issue to watch for -- 7 days.

Comment: I was not the moderator who issued the review ban, but it's become increasingly clear to me that not all reviewers, let alone users, are aware that plagiarism is taken so seriously on the site. And I'm starting to wonder if maybe we do need to inform posters and reviewers upfront after all (and I don't mean the "copied content" option). I speak as someone who was raised with the notion that plagiarism is one of the most disgusting and scummy things a person could do to another person without physically harming them.

Comment: And other thing from that post: "Therefore, let's set a standard that if you find a plagiarized tag wiki or excerpt, meeting the qualifications outlined above, you can flag one of the reviewers' posts detailing what you found. Upon receipt of such a flag, moderators will take action to remove those reviewers from the review queue for x days, where x is a fairly small number at first."

Comment: It didn't even occur to me it was plagiarized. I thought that kind of edit was standard operating procedure. I just hadn't had that kind of review issue before. I think maybe tag edits could get their own queue and there could be a warning or something specific to that content.

Comment: @clearlight: Yeah, I don't blame you. You now know that tag wiki edits are far more likely to be plagiarized than any other type of edit - but you didn't before. So I see where you're coming from.

Comment: The problem with mathematical definitions like this is that every every correct forumlation will be >90% identical and if it isn't it is in most cases at least inaccurate if not wrong.

Comment: Your assertion is clearly not true, @piet, or no one would be able to publish scientific or mathematical papers. Academia has a very high standard for *originality*, while simultaneously maintaining a high standard of *accuracy* and *precision*. So it must not be the case that there is only a single correct formulation and everyone has no choice but to parrot it. If you aren't sure what does or does not constitute plagiarism, then perhaps you should contribute in ways other than reviewing.

Comment: @CodyGray while the high standard for originality certainly holds true for actual content it is certainly not so for definitions of fundamental terms. I'm pretty certain not every one of the hunderds of papers mentioning the definition of e.g. a vector space roll their own formulation - subtle differences in a definition might make it impossible to reuse previous results.

Comment: No, in fact, they often cite prior work. Which makes it not plagiarism. @piet

Comment: @BoltClock informing posters upfront is unlikely to work - anyone can suggest an edit and these "anyone" are same random folks who are known to ignore each and every warning about how to properly ask questions. As for informing reviewers upfront that sounds like a good idea. Reviewers are expected to be attentive anyway so giving them some click-through popup prior to first review of tag wiki edit might work (or if popup fails to teach them this will justify ban when they approve wrong edit)

Comment: @gnat People get popups saying "I agree with the Terms and Conditions" all the time. Years and years of being exposed to this, has trained many people to just click the annoying pop-up away without reading. I'd prefer to give reviewers a little quiz instead - something that forces attention.

Comment: Sso what if it is plagiarized? Using the project's own description (less the marketing hyperbole) often seems to be the best choice for concise descriptions. I've never seen a project or company complain when using it since its free advertising. Stack overflow seems to be identifying a problem where one does not exist.

Answer (score 28):

You are, of course, free to review or not review as you choose. You chose to review and missed a plagiarized edit. So you're off of the review queues for a week. No permanent harm done. This isn't a courtroom and you're not "guilty" of anything. We just want you to take a closer look at future reviews.

There are several ways you could respond to this:

> It makes me want to just skip all tag wiki edits in the future so I don't guess wrong or have to spend 5 or 10 minutes or more trying to check source or authenticity on the off-chance that I'll get my derrier in the wringer if someone happens to find out it was taken wholesale from elsewhere.

That's one. Another would be:

> Maybe I should review more carefully.

Neither one is "right". We're happy to have the community review posts, but we don't want it to become a tedious and unpleasant chore. It's your choice.

Comment: You don't need to use draconian ways to inform (punish) people when clearly the site could take preventative measures too. This is like a stop sign that is partially occluded by trees. You could cut us (three people who were unaware of the plagiarism thing) a little slack with a warning as there is no reason to believe at all any of us would not take the hint or be repeat offenders. I'm not saying there's nothing to learn, but stern rebuke should be counterbalanced with fair warning.

Comment: @clearlight is sad that you see it as punishment, when the action was entirely intended to be corrective.

Comment: Well, if the classic textbook-definition from the above review is plagiarism then the "endpoint of a bidirectional inter-process communication flow across an Internet Protocol-based computer network "-part from the sockets-wiki certainly is too. Shouldn't that be removed or cited as well?

Comment: @piet.t: Yes, and everything that's plagiarized on every part of the site should be removed as well. But that's not the focus here...

Answer (score 23):

> I mean, even in the real world there is something call "fair use" where you're allowed to copy excerpts from proprietary documents/media.

This is important to address, because it is a common confusion. "Fair use" is defense against copyright infringement. **Plagiarism is distinct from copyright infringement.** You could raise a successful fair use defense against a copyright infringement claim, and yet still be deemed to have plagiarized.

Simple example. Alice writes an article in the school's newspaper in which she copies three consecutive sentences out of a 200 page book written by Bob, without attribution (no quotes, no name, nothing):

1. Copyright: if Bob were to want to raise a copyright claim, fair use would be in Alice's favor. She did not copy a whole chapter, it is unlikely that people would buy the newspaper *instead of* buying Bob's book, etc.
2. Plagiarism: This is flat out plagiarism. She did not attribute the copied passage to Bob. It does not matter *one bit* if a court found that it was fair use.

(You also open a whole different can of worms with the term "proprietary", but I'm going to just say that if you think "fair use" is a defense if you leak a little bit of *proprietary* information, you're in for a nasty surprise.)

So if you see something and think "well, this cannot be plagiarism because it is allowed by fair use", well, that's just plain wrong.

Comment: OK, so you caught me. I'm not a lawyer.  Interesting clarifications. I was just reeling because I was busted too hard not really because I wanted to get into a war about what plagiarism is. If I'd known to be on guard for it  I would have been and it didn't need it to be bashed into my thick skull to introduce me to that idea. That's all I'm saying. I'm not unreasonable. I'm bugged now, and feelings bruised but I haven't lost my lucidity or common sense about the fundamental ideas here.

Comment: *"I'm not a lawyer."* I suppose that's Monica Crowley's defense, too. It is a never-ending source of shock and consternation to me how many people see nothing wrong with stealing other people's work and claiming it as their own unless explicitly told otherwise. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm also not the *"perpetrator"* or defending *"plagiarism"*, I'm saying I wasn't aware of the all the legal definitions of it.

Comment: Your arguments beg the question: so what if it is plagiarized? Using the project's own description (less the marketing hyperbole) often seems to be the best choice for concise descriptions. I've never seen a project or company complain when using it since its free advertising. Stack overflow seems to be identifying a problem where one does not exist.

Comment: @jww I'm not deciding here what constitutes plagiarism but reporting on what the community considers to be plagiarism. If you want to change what is and isn't considered plagiarism, that's an argument you must present  to the community.

Comment: @Louis - I went through the Help Center, and nothing forbids using a project's description for the wiki tags. Like I said, some folks are trying to solve a problem that does not exist. Its classic over-engineering. Stack Overflow is full of them.

Comment: @jww: so you are happy to allow copyright violations and plagiarism simply because these are not explicitly mentioned in the help centre, and by claiming companies will appreciate the free advertising. Do you think that'll stand up in court? Companies that want free advertising by having their works copied need to do so explicitly by giving permission to copy boilerplate text, for example.

Comment: @jww: that said, you appear to have missed https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing, [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/160071) and [Users are calling me a plagiarist. What do I do?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/160077).

Comment: @jww: and you won't see companies complain on Meta or to you personally, because they do so using a DMCA complaint to the Stack Overflow legal department. Just because *you* don't see complaints doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I'm going to call you out. Please state a project or company that has complained Stack Overflow used the project's or company's own description in a wiki tag to describe their product. I'm aware of [CipherCloud's DCMA complaint](http://meta.crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/250/ciphercloud-dmca-notice), and I know the underlying issue was their false and misleading marketing (and not a wiki tag). I'm also well aware of the issues in implementing homomorphic encryption (HME) and somewhat  homomorphic encryption (SHE) schemes.

Comment: @jww: I'm a volunteer moderator and not part of the legal department of Stack Overflow. How do you expect me to have any knowledge of such complaints? If you want to discuss the policy on plagiarism, post a new question, this is now way off topic for the discussion here.

Answer (score 15):

> However, to lose full review queue privileges for this seems particularly unfair to me as a first time offense,

You seem to think that this is a particularly severe punishment.  We're not taking your first born, you're just being given a few days without reviewing to take some time to learn more about what you did wrong and how to avoid making the same mistakes in the future.

> and a much grayer area.

It's not really that grey.  Plagiarism is a very serious problem, and this is a very clear instance of it.

> Note that 3 other reviewers also approved it, so there is clearly some confusion and need to educate users better and more reasonably in that area.

Yep.  That's why you guys were banned, to help you realize what you were doing was wrong so you don't continue to make the same mistake.  If you have a suggestion for a better way to inform reviewers of what they need to be doing when reviewing, by all means propose a change.

> There have been no audits to teach/indicate show that this kind of thing is an issue.

Audits aren't going to bring up every situation you need to address.  They're there to filter out the worst of the worst—the most egregious of the bad reviewers.  Not getting banned from audits is a *very* low bar to pass.  And note that when people start failing reviewers for things above that super low bar; getting reviews that require them to actually know how to review, what the are and aren't supposed to do, and not just recognize the most obvious and abusive spam/vandalism, they tend to complain (but we're getting a bit off track now anyway, that's another issue).  Also note that generating reviews that really teach people how to review well is a very hard problem, unlike generating reviews that no sane person should ever fail.

> I have seen many other tag updates like this, so thought it was the norm.

Yes, there are lots of bad reviewers out there.  That's why we have mods taking the time to go out and issue bans like this.  Now you know that it's not right, and you can do better in the future.

> Does this suggest that reviewing tag updates requires us to google the text and try to figure out the source and wording of every tag wiki update? Should we hire a lawyer or a law firm or research agency to check IP too? I'm just saying it can be hard to know where to draw the line on that stuff when it comes down to it.

You should certainly be on the lookout for plagiarized content, yes.  It's one of the most common problems with tag wikis.  In this case, there were a lot of warning signs just from the edit itself: a new tag wiki with a fairly generic description.  For something like that, it's probably worth doing a quick search for, yes.  When it's someone fixing a typo, then obviously that's not going to be a case where you'd really need to consider plagiarism.  As the rejection reason for this issue mentions, just copying a generic description like this also makes for a *bad tag wiki* (in addition to being plagiarism), so that should also be making you look further and question the edit.

You really should be catching the really obvious cases where low-quality tag wikis are suggested based on copying someone's description of their product.  If you occasionally miss some more subtle and hard to notice instances, where there aren't red flags, or the source material isn't easily found, then that's more forgivable.

> To me, this is a whole new gotcha to me and I was completely caught of guard unprepared, and I think, in this case, nailing me to the wall for it is really hitting below the belt or shooting me in the back because there was really no fair warning.

But there was.  There's a whole rejection reason devoted specifically to edits like this.  Basically any guidance you find on how to review tag wikis is also going to address this issue, as it's one of the main issues that tag wiki edits face.  You didn't notice, but the resources were available for you to find out.

> It makes me want to just skip all tag wiki edits in the future so I don't guess wrong or have to spend 5 or 10 minutes or more trying to check source or authenticity on the off-chance that I'll get my derrier in the wringer if someone happens to find out it was taken wholesale from elsewhere.

If you think that reviewing tag wikis is too time-consuming for you, then *by all means*.  It's *much* better for you to just skip the reviews you don't have the time for than to review them incorrectly.  Reviewing is optional; if you don't want to review these posts *then don't*.

> I mean, even in the real world there is something call "fair use" where you're allowed to copy excerpts from proprietary documents/media.

"Fair use" would, at a bare minimum, require a citation here, which was missing.  Without the proper citation, there's *no shot* at a fair-use argument, and even with it, I don't really see most of the points of fair use being applicable here.

> I just didn't realize plagiarism was something that happens here, or that we all as individual have to police it.

And now you know.  Had the moderator not banned you, you wouldn't.

> It seems maybe wiki tag edits should have its own queue due to its different nature from most of the edits, which can be reviewed with more forthrightly.

Feel free to write a proposal for that, if you think it would help.  (Although check for duplicates first; it sounds familiar.)

> I don't think you can really say (or treat me) like what I did was egregious neglect as though I was educated, trained, forewarned, and should have known better. I mean, now I know, it is an issue, but just don't think that ways the way to bring it to my attention, since I've put a lot of effort into serving and trying to do the right thing here, and I find this very discouraging.

Well, it *was* egregious neglect, you failed to address one of the most common, and a fairly serious, problems with tag wiki edits, and you *did* have the information available to you to know that it was wrong—you simply didn't pay close enough attention to it.

> Can I be let off with a warning this time?

Well, it's not my decision to make, but the fact that you're working so hard to try to claim that you didn't do anything wrong, and to blame the system, as well as others, for *your mistake*, on top of your insistence on how unreasonable it is for reviewers to be expected to handle these cases appropriately, rather than taking ownership of what you did wrong, and really trying to convince us that you're not going to make the same mistake in the future, I know I wouldn't support it.  I'd personally only support lifting a ban for someone who was really convincing that they not only knew what they did wrong, but that they aren't going to make the same mistake again.

Comment: Just for completeness, you might want to mention the minimum number of reviews that one needs to get wrong before we take their first born.

Comment: You make a lot of good points except that I think you've over-implied that I should have known about plagiarism since those edits are thrown in the same queue as all the other ones where people are reviewing many queues which have very different standards of judgement.  I think I should have been *warned* once instead of banned. That's my main point. The other stuff about the finer points of plagiarism is secondary to that.

Comment: @CodyGray ha ha ha "take their first born". ha ha ha. Funny stuff, punishment.

Comment: @clearlight If your "standard of judgement" is that plagiarism is fine, then you shouldn't be reviewing.  There are somethings that, when reviewing, are matters of opinion and that different reviewers will disagree on, but if you think plagiarism is fine *then the ban is 100% warranted*, because that's wrong, and it's not a subjective opinion.  I'd also say that reading throw the rejection reasons is a pretty darn low bar to expect of a reviewer.  I don't see it as unreasonable to expect that of a reviewer.

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think this is just. You say the tools were available to know, but I think they were a little more far-fetched than you are implying. And your burden of contriteness on my part is really unreasonable. Please be fair whether or not someone grovels, IMO. I *never* implied in any thing I said that I didn't recognize it's wrong approve plagiarism. Everything I said showed I accept *that* concept and would deal with it. It's all about the fact that this caught me and several others off guard because it is outside the norm. Just wanted a warning because I would have learned from it.

Comment: You addressed your comment to the wrong person. I didn't write this answer. I do agree, though, that throwing a fit about how unjust the ban was does tend to send the wrong message about your understanding regarding the seriousness of plagiarism… @clear

Comment: @Servy, again - at NO point in ANY of this did I imply that plagiarism should be tolerated nor that I refused to take responsibility, in retrospect, for either policing it or skipping it. That's all your conjecture, and if it is, that's untrue and again unfair to me. I understand now and would have with a warning. As for going through all the rejection reasons before reviewing -that's also a good idea but maybe a little more advanced considering how people are introduced to the queues and work them. Again, I am open to learning from good suggestions. But more reasonable is to teach not punish

Comment: @CodyGray you are hearing what you want to hear. You don't like that I'm upset, but in spite of my being upset, I understand the fundamental issue and never disputed it, I took it to heart, *and I would have if there was any slippery when wet sign* that was clearly visible under the conditions.

Comment: @clearlight You [blamed people for not assuming your innocence](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341327/?noredirect=1#comment431138_341327) which is an odd thing to do when you're not claiming that you're innocent, you're asserting that [this is a matter of opinion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341327/?noredirect=1#comment431156_341331) rather than a clear mistake.  And no, your posts/comments *isn't* convincing me that you know you made a mistake.  You haven't outright stated innocence, but you haven't admitted guilt either.

Comment: @clearlight well...... reading the possible reasons to reject is clearly visible under the conditions, no? I mean.... if I am to review, I believe I should at LEAST read all the reasons into why something isn't appropriate :/. In any case, considering you say stuff like "I don't think you can really say (or treat me) like what I did was egregious neglect" (I know there IS important context in the rest of the sentence that changes what it means, but I can see how it can also be read as you denying it's an issue).

Comment: @Servy You will win this argument because you are more powerful. I said in the future I would probably skip wiki edit reviews if I didn't want to do the legwork of checking for plagiarism. That is a tacit but clear acknowledgement of the validity of the core concern. It's pretty obvious that I'm upset about being taken off guard by this and nothing else. The concept could  have been more reasonably introduced to me without dinging me hard for it. That is really my only objection and the point I'm arguing. I'm sorry you think I'm advocating plagiarism or negligent reviews but I never have.

Comment: Servy "wins" this one because of logic, not power

Comment: @Clive. He's logical, makes many excellent points, but he's wrong in his inference of my reluctance to learn the lesson about what plagiarism is or my willingness to change my behavior appropriately in response to it.  I still insist this was not a fair way to 'teach me a lesson' in this case, when if the sign on the road was less obscured by trees I would have seen it.

Comment: @clearlight FYI, when someone tells you that you haven't convinced them that you recognize what you did was wrong, and that you're not going to do it again, it's a lit easier to just *explicitly state that you know what you did was wrong, and to indicate that you're not going to make the same mistake in the future*.  When you just continue on the attack, blaming other people for the problem, you're only validating the statements that you're attempting to contradict.

Comment: You know by now where I stand. I didn't get where I have so far because I'm a stubborn fool trying to thwart the guidelines. I've worked very hard here and I'm still willing to work and learn to advance here. But I am offended by injustice. On top of everything I'm sorry I'm not the perfect boy scout and have feelings that can get bruised but that's all this is. I'm a Beatle, not a Rolling Stone. I'm really not a bad kid once you get to know me.

Comment: Any way, if you want to hear the actual words, "I love you". Okay, I love you. I get your points. I respect your message. I will do better next time. I will google for plagiarism. I will check the rejection reasons and try to inform myself about each review task and the options better.  But do I think I was dinged too hard for this offense this time? Yes, I still do.

Comment: This Is getting a bit weird now - too many metaphors, feels like you're quoting song lyrics - is this really as a big a deal to you as you're making out?

Comment: @clearlight So when I say, "You're not convincing me that you're not going to make the same mistake again, perhaps saying that you're not going to make the same mistake again would help address that" responding with, "you know where I stand" is perhaps not the best way to go about that.  Going on and on about how you're trying to thwart the guidelines and how we shouldn't be stopping you from doing that and the great "injustice" against you is literally doing the exact opposite of that.  I thought I was giving you a great out; and you just went right in the other direction with that.

Comment: Darkness at the break of noon shadows even the silver spoon, 
The handmade blade, the child's balloon eclipses both the sun and moon, to understand you know too soon, there is no sense in trying,
Pointed threats, they bluff with scorn,
Suicide remarks are torn,
From the fool's gold mouthpiece,
The hollow horn plays wasted words,
Proves to warn that he not busy being born,
Is busy dying. Temptation's page flies out the door,
You follow, find yourself at war,
Watch waterfalls of pity roar,
You feel to moan but unlike before,
You discover that you'd just be,
One more person crying

Comment: (that last one was to @Clive ;) ) It's Bob Dylan

Comment: @Servy I don't know what to say. I feel this is more about telling me how to feel and behave when punished. I'm serious. I get all of your points. I agree with everything you said. I'm just saying if I got a tamer warning I would have learned all the same things. I'm hard enough on myself. I am trying to do the right thing and hate screwing up enough already. If I'd known to be on guard for that kind of thing I would have been. What do you want from me? To beg? Seriously, yes I'm still bugged, but I agree with over 95% of what you've said.

Comment: @clearlight Your warning was *very* tame.  Almost as tame as it gets, as far as review errors go.  It doesn't really get tamer, other than perhaps having a 3 day review ban instead of a 7 day ban.  And as I've said like half a dozen times now, if you honestly realize you made a mistake, and are going to take steps to rectify that, then , *say that*, rather than going on a rant attacking everyone else and not taking responsibility, and don't try to blame others or excuse the mistake, if you honestly realize that you made a mistake.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you on the task-related issues but I am not giving you my first born in terms of begging you for mercy and saying I had no valid points here. I think you too could overlook some of my frustration under the circumstances. How to beg forgiveness in a consensus way feels out of scope for the task, by saying I didn't need to be banned to learn this. I'm telling you, I get it. I will deal with it. I'm asking for the ban to be lifted. I'm asking you to do that because I think it's fair.

Comment: I will tell you this @Servy, I would personally lift the ban for you or someone else under the circumstances if I thought there was a chance the ban went too far, regardless of them getting spun up about it.

Comment: @clearlight I was *very* clear about why I don't support lifting your ban.  It has nothing to do with you being upset.  It has everything to do with you blaming other people, not taking responsibility for your actions, indicating that you'd make the same mistake again if given the chance, and that the ban is simply warranted given the action you took.  That I've had to ask you like a dozen times to even admit that you made a mistake says a *lot*. It shouldn't be that hard for you to admit that you make a mistake if you know that you made a mistake.

Comment: You are WRONG about that: "indicating that you'd make the same mistake again if given the chance". I NEVER thought that, I would NEVER intentionally do that, and I NEVER implied that and if you inferred that, that was not what I wanted to elicit. It does not represent my perspective, which I've tried to clarify many times. How many times do I have to tell you I agree with all your task-related criticisms? You are not going to help me with the ban because you are insisting you think I have a position I absolutely don't have.

Comment: @clearlight You said that it was unreasonable for anyone to check for plagiarism, and you went on about it for a while.  If you're saying that it's unreasonable to review the posts correctly, then the only assumption I can reasonably make is that you have no intention of reviewing the posts correctly.

Comment: @Servy I pondered whether it was the kind of thing that could be thoroughly and reasonably checked - or that I wanted to have to do that. But it is very presumptuous and not true that I mean, "and therefore I would let plagiarism slide nor do some kind of reasonable googling or scrutiny if I took on that suggested edit wiki review task". I'm not advocating for plagiarism or negligence in any way, but a moment of frustration I just had to wonder if it's worth reviewing those things. Of course at some point I'll be OK with it and add that extra step and would have in the first place if I knew to

Comment: @clearlight Had you said that you didn't realize you needed to check for plagiarism, and that you'll now start checking for plagiarism, that would have been *radically* different than you saying that you can't be reasonably expected to check for plagiarism.  Notice how one of those things is refusing to admit a mistake, accusing others, and indicating that the bad behavior will continue, one is recognizing an error and indicating that it won't happen again.

Comment: @Servy, I've spend hours a night for the past week and a half working on reviews and this site always intending to improve and do the right thing. That's why having this happen stings so much. It wasn't necessary. I am self-correcting.

Comment: @clearlight Then it sounds like you could use the break.  You appear to be spending way too much time reviewing.

Comment: @Servy - it sounds like I'm damned if I do and damned if I don't with you. You simply will not do anything to help or acknowledge any potential wrongdoing or over-zealous punitive behavior on the site's part and I think that is really unreasonable of you. I slowed down the review tasks and was paying very close attention to my reviews and passed many audits. The issue this time wasn't that I was working too hard it's that I didn't know I should be checking for plagiarism and that is all.

Comment: @Servy, okay, you helped by documenting things and explaining things. I tried to acknowledge the core lesson was learned but you seem to refuse to do any favors for people who don't conform to your idea of social etiquette, and yet let the site off too easily for it's perhaps misapplication of power.  Like mgt. always protects mgt. in most places. It's subtle corruption, IMO. I am not disputing you're more expert or an authority or most of your technical/procedural points. But I think you are being unfair.

Comment: @clearlight Why, after all this time, do you still seem to think that the way to get unbanned is to go around insulting everyone else and blaming other people for your mistake?  Do you honestly think that that's going to get you unbanned, or is that not actually your goal here?

Comment: @Servy I'm saying  ban went too far. That's my point. You didn't need to do that to a hardworking contributing well-intentioned member that has corrected every behavior possible when it has come to their attention. While you're trying to tell me HOW I have to ask for justice and tell you I have learned the task-related points, I'm telling you that there is a point you can concede in all fairness but won't and that there are two sides to this coin and that it is not only on me to learn a lesson and acknowledge something. Don't need ban lifted so much that I'lll roll over on that point.

Comment: @Servy I want to save my skin but I hate authoritarians who abuse their power whether it be Trump or anyone else.

Comment: @clearlight I literally have no more authority in this matter than any other member of the community.  You have just as much authority in this issue as I do, so continuing to insult me by calling me an authoritarian is not only continuing to do exactly what you've been told a dozen times you shouldn't be doing (insulting people) but it's just patently false.  And you even know it's false, because you've been told as much already.  Anyway, I'm not interested in sitting here being insulted anymore.  You know what you did wrong, it's up to you to do better in the future.

Comment: @Servy - you held out the carrot of being able to unban me and then indicated you would not because you presumed that I was saying I would not respond to that review task appropriately. I said I learned the lesson, would have without ban and will do better. And now you're saying that even if I'm insulted and made wrong on everything I said, that I can not rebut those points or get miffed. I think that is a subtle abuse of power and there is a tinge of dishonesty in your response. I guess I'm risking burning bridges with that level of honesty but it is how I feel.

Comment: @Servy I know you are talented, experienced, skilled, hard working, intelligent, and correct on most things, but I don't think you admit when you're wrong or concede any points.  I can do that, so maybe you have something to learn from me too. I'm not incorrect about everything and you are not correct about everything, but you are holding all the cards here.

Comment: @clearlight I thought the answer was pretty explicit, "Well, it's not my decision to make," that it's not my decision to make.  Given that I've responded to several dozen comments of yours, I fail to see how you think you're not being given an opportunity to rebut any of my points.  You've primarily used that opportunity to just insult me, rather than anything else, but you've had lots of opportunities.  Too many, probably.

Comment: @Servy - OK, fair enough. Thank you for taking so much time to clarify. Either way I'll get over this, and I'm too invested here to just walk away, and I love most things about this site. I am trying to improve my skills all the time and help people. I might have a temper and be oversensitive about what I consider slights and that's a character flaw but it's not easy to correct. I like you, I appreciate you but I still think you should have cut me more slack and understand why I'm upset and let some of that slide.

Comment: @clearlight If you want people to give you the benefit of the doubt and forgive your mistake, then I would suggest not insulting them dozens of times.  Maybe I'm abnormal, but it just doesn't make me want to overlook someone's mistake when they're constantly insulting me for their own mistake.

Comment: @Servy, but the site made a mistake in how they alerted me to the issue too. In all fairness you should be willing to admit that maybe SO or the moderator went too far under the circumstances whether or not you like the fact that I fought back when challenged on everything.  Yes, technically I made a mistake but it is not as obvious or easy to know the guidelines in that area or how to avoid it, so that is where the site could improve. Bashing me so hard for it in the first place I believe was as wrong as what I did if not more so.

Comment: @Servy at least in human terms.  I did not lash out first.

Comment: Having to beg for mercy and justice and fairness is dehumanizing, or having to sugarcoat things to get fair treatment on an issue just seems wrong no matter how you cut it.

Comment: @clearlight If you want to propose improved ways of teaching reviewers how to review, then by all means.  That doesn't justify constantly insulting people.  I've also explained, several times, how I feel the ban was warranted, you've given me no reason to think that it wasn't.  Your highly inappropriate and abusive behavior here has only cemented that it *was* warranted.  If you didn't want anyone to explain why you were in the wrong, then you shouldn't have made a public post asking people to explain why what you did was wrong.  I was just answering your question.

Comment: @clearlight If you think it's dehumanizing to admit your mistake when you've made a mistake when requesting that other people overlook your mistake and reverse your entirely deserved consequences, then I guess that's an opinion you can hold.  And yet, if you want to ask for people to overlook your mistake and reverse the consequences of it, you're going to have to admit that you made the mistake and apologize for it.  Or you can just accept the consequences of your actions, it's really up to you.  Personally I'm the type to just accept the consequences of my actions, but that's just me.

Comment: Obvious troll is obvious?

Comment: @TinyGiant, I'm not trolling Servy. I've told him countless times I have accepted the task-related points. I also said I would have responded appropriately if I'd known in the first place and any visible stop sign (warning) would have been enough to alert me to the issue without having to be banned. I'm not saying letting plagiarism in is right, I'm saying I didn't check because I hadn't figured out that I needed to and that's the only reason. This big "BUT YOU MADE A MISTAKE AND MUST PAY" thing is absurd under the circumstances. But yeah, it's time to drop it and live with it.

Comment: @Servy, I have conceded a lot to you. I've told you I don't dislike you, don't disrespect you. I think you're a great asset to the site. I thanked you for taking all this time to debate this with me. I told you I said the things I did *because* I was challenged and not given the benefit of the doubt on anything despite my service and overall good work and intentions here. I may have implied there is some abuse of authority in this and slight dishonesty for not cutting me slack on *anything* but that's about it.  I will get over it. I respect you, appreciate you and I will live.

Comment: But you're wrong. You wouldn't have responded appropriately, as you have proven by exploding into a ball of flame at the first instance of someone correcting your behavior while at no point accepting responsibility for your actions, accepting the criticism, or improving your future behavior.

Comment: @TinyGiant - BS, I've acknowledged a LOT here. I'm only disputing one thing repeatedly and that's that I don't believe I got fair notice of the issue and was unaware of that particular duty. But I know about it now.  Some say I did. I know how to inform myself better in the future and acknowledged that. I'm saying the mod went too far, and I still believe I'm correct about that. And I think it is slightly libelous to say I have not learned or acknowledge the task-related thing I am supposed to learn. And I quibble with that need to sugarcoat the dialog to get justice on the main point I raised

Comment: @clear Ranting and raving repeatedly will not change anything. As you have been told repeatedly: **If you would like to suggest a change to the system, post a feature request**. The system has been explained to you repeatedly, now do something about it!

Comment: @TinyGiant but the SO mod should not have banned me as a first warning on that particular task. Maybe nothing will change but that was inadvertently abusive and reckless. I am not this big sinner of the review queues who is recklessly doing wrong things and needs to be punished for that. It could have been handled with more respect, intelligence and deference in the first place, so don't just make me wrong. I KNOW I'm not the only one who's misacted here.

Comment: @clear To sum up your last comment: **You** think that the way the system works right now could be improved, and have a suggestion on how to improve this and reasoning as to why it should be improved. **POST A FEATURE REQUEST**. The way the system works now has been explained to you. You've said that the mod acted incorrectly, but they acted as expected by the system.

Comment: OK I will look into that. But I also think the moderator doled out too heavy a punishment for that. And I resent it.

Comment: @clear Regardless of whether you resent it or not, that is how it is currently done. If you think that how it is currently done should be changed, you should post a feature request. (Do you see how annoying it is when people keep repeating the same thing over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over and over again?)

Comment: It's been dialog with my defending my initial complete and rebutting detractions from it. I haven't been saying la la la la. I've been accused of hyperbole in this thread. Now it's your turn. Anyway, I guess this is done.

Comment: @Servy I still think you're absolutely incorrect that a 7 day ban was justified under the circumstances, just because I *could* have known. Yeah but the way I 'could' have known is not a common or documented way to 'know', and 7 days for a first offense is just nasty and draconian based on the relevant discussion someone posted in a comment to another answer stating what comprises plagiarism and how to handle  offenders who don't know of the issue. Your wish that I kiss your derrier in order for you to think I should have gotten justice and fair treatment in the first place is just bogus.

Comment: @Servy See about the spirit of the law. Even the people concerned about this issue had much fairer, reaslitic, reasonable ways of handling it, and your defense of thowing the book at a first time offender with this says a lot about the kind of person you are. Sorry, but your stubborn insistence that for one reason or another I should get such harsh rebuke is sadistc on some level. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip

Comment: @Servy you say you think I was insulting? Well I resent being treated unfairly and I found your defense of it insulting.

Comment: @clearlight Why do you *still* think that the way to go about getting unbanned is to continue insulting me?  I've told you like a dozen times that insulting me isn't a constructive way to go about getting yourself unbanned, and yet you continue to do so.  Apparently you're not one to actually heed warnings, so I don't know why you'd insist that you should be given more of them; you're not giving me any reason to believe you'd have cared even if you were.

Comment: @Servy no one is unbanning me, and you're just screwing with me to suggest I should beg for it or asking for it nicely would make any difference. You've told me I'm hosed so I know there's nothing I can do. I'm just being honest with you. You rubbed it in and defended an unjust punishment, so you are as big a problem here as anything, and just because you think you're a high muckity muck and can mess with people who don't fawn over your every word doesn't make it right, and I don't appreciate how you handled this anymore than how you think I did.

Comment: @clearlight You're probably right that nobody is unbanning you at this point.  You've acted highly inappropriately, not given good reasons to merit your unbanning, and provided *tons* of evidence to support why your banning was merited, which I explained in my answer and comments.  Had you actually acted appropriately in your meta post here I strongly suspect you could have gotten unbanned; I see people *constantly* get their review bans reversed when they've made it clear that they understand their mistake, how to avoid making it again, and are civil in their discussion of their ban.

Comment: @Servy That is LUDICROUS. If the initial ban wasn't justified, letting it persist because I'm not happy about it nor begging for mercy is unjustified. This little dance-for-the-mean-puppeteers or you'll get no justice game you keep playing is corrupt.

Comment: @Servy I will fight tyranny *wherever* I see it.

Comment: @clearlight I never said the initial ban wasn't justified.  It was justified.  You made a serious and egregious error.  Had you demonstrated that the ban was no longer necessary, you may have been able to convince a mod to rescind it.  All I've ever seen from you is indications that you really needed the ban, and most certainly aren't ready to go back to reviewing yet.  Hopefully you will be ready by the time your ban ends, so you don't end up right back in the same position.  Or you could just keep insulting the people that are trying to help you and just end up with an account suspension.

Comment: @Servy, again, it wasn't justified   as any reasonable person knows, and what happened to me was not in the initial spirit of the law. It was draconian and unnecessary. and should never have happened.  And the people who tried to create the rules this *knew* it was unfair to nail  people who did this unwares. The ban was just supposed to be enough to get first time offender's attention and nothing more. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip I'm not buying your BS. You're just an authoritarian with a sociopathic streak, expecting people to beg you.

Comment: @Servy *And* while you're being holier than thou about it, the article also points out the main purpose is to discourage the theft of *creative content*, that was a VERY short passage of what hardly passes for "creative content". In all ways this should have maybe been a 1 day ban tops, or some other warning. That would have easily sufficed.

Comment: @Servy, and if you're saying only people who are nice and contrite here are deserving of justice, I don't think you meet the standard either.

Answer (score 10):

Draconian, meaning too severe of a punishment, does not seem to fit the scenario here.

This was the edit review:

[image]

It was small enough, and tag wikis in general are so prone to plagiarism, that doing even a very small bit of inspecting would have shown the problem.

Googling the first sentence brings this up:

[image]

**You should have looked**. Plagiarism is a huge problem, *especially when missed in review queues*. This is still a problem plaguing the new Documentation feature.

The review queues are there for oversight, and if you cannot perform the task of actually *reviewing* the content, then it most certainly is time to step back and reflect on what it is exactly that you are doing when using that feature.

You got a small review ban, not a ban from using the site or posting questions. That is the consequence of your actions. Own up to it. Learn from it.

Comment: Most people don't approach the queues knowing plagiarism is a huge problem. I didn't know to check for that. I was checking for clarity, relevance, editing and formatting errors like other suggested edits. That is a consequence of my own actions, but also an overzealous way of impugning me for missing a not-so-obvious aspect of the requirements of this particular kind of review task. My ONLY dispute here is that I think the mod went overboard in how it was brought to my attention as a first offense under the circumstances. Pretty unkind and unnecessary to a mostly good contributor

Comment: @clearlight `Most people don't approach the queues knowing plagiarism is a huge problem.` 
Well now you know. That's the purpose of the ban - to bring it to your attention that you are doing something wrong. Take some time off and chill/reflect.

Comment: @SamuelLiew yeah, why ask someone nicely when beating them over the head will suffice? But OK, no one acknowledges I have a valid point, and we're all getting tired of discussing/hearing about it, so, whatever. I don't think you're all wrong, I don't think I'm all wrong. I think the mod went overboard, but nothing I can do about it.

Comment: @clear no one has said that your point is invalid. Everyone has been telling you that this is the way the system currently works. If you would like to change how the system works, you need to post a feature request to that effect. You're repeatedly saying that the system does not work the way you think it should work, but you have yet to post a feature request to change that.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Thanks for trying to be cool about it.